# Setting multiple Tag checkboxes as "Selected" from Array

Tags: php, laravel

Struggling with something simple!

I'm new to Laravel 8 and have a number of checkboxes which are dynamically created saving their values to an array. My problem occurs when i want to flag previously active options as "selected".

The problem appears to be with the in_array argument and where i'm creating the array..

```
@php 
    $currentTags = $prop->tags->pluck('id'); 
@endphp   

@foreach($tags as $tag)
    <div class="custom-control custom-switch">
        <input type="checkbox"
            @if(in_array($tag->id, $currentTags)) selected @endif 
            class="custom-control-input" 
            onclick="$(this).val(this.checked ? {{ $tag->id }} : 0)" 
            id="tags[{{ $tag->id }}]" 
            name="tags[{{ $tag->id }}]">
        <label class="custom-control-label" for="tags[{{ $tag->id }}]">{{ $tag->name }}</label>
    </div>
@endforeach
```

---

Error
TypeError
in_array(): Argument #2 ($haystack) must be of type array, Illuminate\Support\Collection

Comment: The error is rather clear - it expects an array, but you gave it an object of type `Illuminate\Support\Collection`. If you check out the [documentation](https://laravel.com/api/5.5/Illuminate/Support/Collection.html#method_all) of that class, you'll see it has a method called `all` that retreives collection items as an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [@El_Vanja](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4205384/el-vanja) commented:

> The error is rather clear - it expects an array, but you gave it an object of type Illuminate\Support\Collection. If you check out the documentation of that class, you'll see it has a method called all that retreives collection items as an array.

Also should change `selected` to `checked`.

**change this**

```php
@if(in_array($tag->id, $currentTags)) selected @endif
```

**To**

```php
@if(in_array($tag->id, $currentTags->toArray())) checked @endif
```

or

```php
@if(in_array($tag->id, $currentTags->all())) checked @endif
```

Comment: Needle comes first, haystack second in `in_array`.

Comment: If you agree, why have you then reversed the order of the arguments and put haystack first?

Comment: fixed it. PHP functions are not consistent I always forget which comes first

Comment: @El_Vanja - Thanks very much!